# Print array in reverse order -- can't find the issue

Tags: java, arrays

Really don't know why this won't print anything. Clearly I'm doing something wrong but I can't think right now.

```
public class warmup13 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = new int[] { 3, 2, 98, 32, 12, 1 };
    }

    public static int[] reverse(int[] intArray) {
        int[] arr = new int[intArray.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = intArray[intArray.length - i - 1];
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
        return arr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it should?

Comment: You never call your `reverse` method.

Comment: [How to call a method in Java](http://www.wikihow.com/Call-a-Method-in-Java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `main` method needs to include a function call to `reverse`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = new int[] { 3, 2, 98, 32, 12, 1 };
    reverse(a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Warmup13{

   //main function initializes array and calls reverse function
   public static void main(String[] args){  
      int[] a= new int[]{3, 2, 98, 32, 12, 1};
      reverse(a);
    }
   // void function prints the array in reverse order
   private static void reverse(int[] intArray) {

       for (int i = intArray.length-1; i >=0; i--){
            System.out.println(intArray[i]);
    }
  }
}
```